# Difficulty while converting string(date) to milliseconds In java

Tags: java, string, date, string-parsing

I have the following code. I am passing `start = "2016/01/01 23:59:59"` and `end = "2017/01/01 23:59:59"`

```
func(String start, String end) {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date1 = sdf1.parse(start);
    long startTime = date1.getTime();
    \\System.out.println(startTime);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date2 = sdf2.parse(end);
    long endTime = date2.getTime();
    \\System.out.println(endTime);
```

}

I am getting the following error

`error: unreported exception ParseException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
      Date date = sdf.parse(time);
                           ^`

How do I rectify this ? And also, Why is it showing me this error ?

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class and friends. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). `LocalDateTime.parse(start, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")).atZone(ZonId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli()`.

Comment: As Ole V.V. commented, FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Hints: `String::replace( " " , "T" )`, `LocalDateTime.parse`,  `LocalDateTime::atZone`, `ZoneId`, `ZonedDateTime::toInstant()`, `Instant::toEpochMilli`.

Comment: @OleV.V. May I know the time complexity of using these inbuilt functions ?

Comment: I don’t know, @yahooo. Never was an issue to me. I would generally expect them to take constant time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`DateFormat#parse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) methods throws a `ParseException`.  This means that if something goes wrong when parsing a string into a date, this exception may be thrown.

One fix is to just declare your method to throw this exception, e.g.

```
public long yourMethod() throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date1 = sdf1.parse(start);
    long startTime = date1.getTime();

    return startTime;
}
```

Or, also taking the advice from the error message, you could place the code into a `try catch` block:

```
public long yourMethod() {
    long startTime = -1L;
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date1 = sdf1.parse(start);
        startTime = date1.getTime();
    }
    catch (ParseException e) {
        // something went wrong
    }

    return startTime;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Also, May I know why it is showing me this error? I am passing the date of the specified format.

Comment: @yahooo Check my updated answer.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: @BasilBourque I agree completely, but perhaps the OP asked about Java 7 dates because he is bound to use them for some reason (e.g. I myself am currently using Java 6 for a legacy project).

Comment: FYI, nearly all the *java.time* functionality is found in *ThreeTen-Backport* project for Java 6 & 7 with virtually identical API. Further adapted to Android <26 in *ThreeTenABP* project.

Comment: No one is going into their legacy code base to introduce the three ten backport project.  The OP is not asking about the date API anyway.